# Difficulties in recollecting memory, when execution speed of an action is slow

Tags: neuroscience, memory

I learnt to solve Rubik's cube 2 - 3 years ago, I used to practice once in a while, I can solve Rubik's cube within a minute.

One day, I went to my uncle's house, my nephew had a Rubik's cube, I wanted to solve it, it was so damaged, that it took on average 3 seconds to make one turn, I keep forgetting the intermediate steps, while trying to solve it. I was not under any emotional stress or pressure at that moment, eventually I quit. And, I went to my home, I tried to solve using my Rubik's cube, I was able to solve it. Why I'm unable to solve the same, when I do it slowly?

I can assume, it has something to do with muscle memory, since I've been solving Rubik's cube, for few years, why I fail to remember, when doing it slow?

Comment: Interesting observation. Generally, we don't answer personal questions, but I can add to this observation that, when performing *kata* in a different rhythm, or doing it slower than usual, or there is a break because the *sensei* stops the *kata* for a while to explain something, I also get confused a lot of times. [*kata* are fixed flows of techniques in karate. *sensei* is a karate teacher]

Comment: thanks for the answer @AliceD

Comment: It wasn't really meant as an answer as such, just as a sort of anecdote to back up your personal observation.